# How to find the key for a JSON value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string `"{name :\"daijiepei\"}"`.  I'm using a JObject to deserialize it:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(str);
string value = obj["name"];
```

So I can get the value, but I can't get the JSON key.
How do I get the key for a JSON value?

Comment: `string key = obj.Properties().ElementAt(0).Name;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the `Properties` method of `JObject` and get the `Key` property from there. Example code from the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JObjectProperties.htm).

```
JObject o = new JObject
{
    { "name1", "value1" },
    { "name2", "value2" }
};

foreach (JProperty property in o.Properties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " - " + property.Value);
}
// name1 - value1
// name2 - value2

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> property in o)
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.Key + " - " + property.Value);
}
// name1 - value1
// name2 - value2
```